# how to bind a directive var to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a problem with using 2 way binding in angular, when i change my input, the change dosnt affect to controller. but the first init from controller affect directive.

in the picture i changed the value, but `vm.date` still have value test.

[image]

[image]

my directive:

```
    (function (app) {
    app.directive('datePicker', function () {

        //Template
        var template = function (element, attrs) {

            htmltext =

                '<input ng-readonly="true" type="text" id="' + attrs.elementId +
                '" ng-model="' + attrs.model + '" type="date" />';

            return htmltext;

        }

        //Manipulation
        var link = function ($scope, elements, attrs, ctrls) {

            //Declare variables we need
            var el = '#' + attrs.elementId + '';
            var m = attrs.model;
            var jdate;
            var date;
            $scope[attrs.model] = [];

            $(el).on('change', function (v) {
                jdate = $(el).val();
                gdate = moment(jdate, 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                if (moment(gdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()) {
                    date = new Date(gdate);

                    $scope[m][0] = date;
                    $scope[m][1] = jdate;
                    //console.log($scope[m]);
                    $scope.vm[m] = $scope[m];

                    console.log($scope.vm); //----> Here Console Write Right Data 

                } else {
                    //console.log('Oh, SomeThing is Wrong!');
                }

            }); 

        } // end of link
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {vm: '='},
            template: template,
            link: link
        };

    });
}(angular.module('app')));
```

and my controller:

```
(function (app) {
    app.controller('test', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.date = 'test';
        vm.mydate = 'test2';
    }]);
}(angular.module('app')));
```

and html:

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="test as vm">

        <date-picker element-id="NN" model="vm.date" vm="vm"></date-picker>
        <p>{{vm.date}}</p>

        <date-picker element-id="NN2" model="vm.mydate" vm="vm"></date-picker>
        <p>{{vm.mydate}}</p>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you print vm in HTML? right after the ng-controller add {{vm}}

Comment: yes i can see the vm but when i need vm.date or something else, show the result that i said.

Comment: Your controller has a `date` property, not a `vm.date` property.

Comment: @zeroflagL Tnx, my mistakes kills me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer:

Your controller has a date property, not a vm.date property. – zeroflagL May 25 at 13:48

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you made the textbox as readonly, but if you remove that readonly and try to update the textbox then the two way binding works. Here's the fiddle for that

https://fiddle.jshell.net/dzfe50om/

Comment: thanks for editing, i checked your code but i need to change the binded value with a 3th party script, my input should be read only. so have another solution?

Comment: for more detail i'm working on a datepicker. and i use (JQuery Calendars)

Comment: Ok, so it means, you are using a jQuery plugin which changes the value in the textbox behind the scenes, can you edit the html part for that in the jsfiddle which i shared or create a new one.

Answer (score -1):

You should define vm to $scope instead of this;

```
var vm = $scope;
```

Comment: I don't think that should affect

Comment: @psychodramatic |  
`var vm = this;` is same as `var vm = $scope;`